# Did Napoléon Bonaparte ask his wife Josephine not to bathe for several days in a letter before his arrival?

Tags: history, quotes

[According to](https://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/london-life/historian-obsessed-with-napoleon-spills-the-beans-on-bonaparte-s-sex-life-and-reveals-the-truth-about-not-tonight-josephine-10309683.html) British historian [Andrew Roberts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Roberts,_Baron_Roberts_of_Belgravia), Napoléon Bonaparte wrote a letter to his wife Joséphine, in which he wrote "to her, ‘don’t wash for three days’" to spice up their reunion. This seems to be a common story also found in many [other sources](https://perfumesociety.org/history/napoleon-josephine-and-a-giant-bill-for-cologne/) such as [blogs](https://theamericanscholar.org/dirty-love/) and [this popular science book](https://www.rsc.org/news-events/articles/2012/02-february/no-sweat-is-bad-news-for-lovers-says-co-author-of-rsc-book/) on the biochemistry of attraction.

Some sources seem to be skeptical about the authenticity of this request and [call it an urban](https://www.historicmysteries.com/sexiness-stink-attraction-to-body-odor/) legend. In an [episode from the BBC show QI](https://www.comedy.co.uk/tv/qi/episodes/10/3/), it is claimed that "Napoleon did not say many of things we attribute to him to Josephine. There is no evidence that he told Josephine not to wash. The earliest source for this quote is 1981"

According to [this neurobiology paper](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Are%20humans%20constantly%20but%20subconsciously%20smelling%20themselves%3F&btnG=), the source might be "de Tourtier-Bonazzi C, Tulard J. 1981 Napoléon. Lettres d’amour à Joséphine", which is probably the source from 1981 mentioned in the QI script. [According to this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Did-Napoleon-really-write-home-in-three-days-dont-wash-to-his-wife), the passage might possibly be found on page 155 of the book, although the contributor on Quora does not claim to have checked the book. The authors of the neurobiology paper also only claim that the quote is "attributed" to the respective book, and seem not to have read it themselves.

The 1981 book, simply judging by its cover, does not strike me as fiction or apocryphal, thus I am skeptical about its dismissal by the BBC show "QI". One of its [authors was a historian at the Sorbonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Tulard).

Comment: I don't think people bathed that often back then that that would have been a concern. They took a bath every other month or so, even if they didn't really need to do so.

Comment: @David Hammen You might very well be right (but I'm not well-versed on 19th century personal hygiene). Perhaps I should have added that the alleged letter is sometimes (allegedly) translated with "wash" instead of "bathe". To my knowledge, washing was much more common than bathing, around 18 hundred.

Comment: Epic, [Louis XIV of France, for example, is said to have taken only two baths in his adult lifetime — both times recommended by his doctors.](https://www.voanews.com/a/science-health_historian-explores-evolution-personal-hygiene/6187950.html) Frequent bathing was generally perceived as not just unhealthy, but very unhealthy. Frequent baths / showers is a rather recent phenomenon.

Comment: @DavidHammen Most people didn't bathe much, but Josephine did "Like Napoleon, Josephine was very particular about cleanliness, bathing daily" https://www.google.com/books/edition/Josephine/5tSq5awNgXUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=napoleon%20josephine%20bathing%20daily

Comment: Bathing was viewed quite differently back then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I obtained the purported citation *Lettres d’amour à Joséphine* (Fayard, 1981), which was also mentioned [by Chantal Jacquet in *Le Monde* in 2013](https://www.lemonde.fr/vous/article/2013/02/14/l-odeur-de-l-autre-est-propice-a-l-eclosion-du-desir_1831025_3238.html). Page 155 does not contain anything like the phrase “*Ne te lave pas, j'accours et dans huit jours je suis là*”. It is a personal letter about Napoleon sending some decorative plants to Josephine and complaining about a blister on his arm. I don't see any other mention of odor in this book ([and others didn't either](http://pekingdork.blogspot.com/2016/04/the-story-about-napoleon-josephine-is.html?showComment=1516231818188#c1946341722949352936)).

I additionally searched two books by Chantal Jacquet which she wrote about odor: [À vue de nez](https://books.openedition.org/editionscnrs/46002?query=Napol%C3%A9on%20) (2022) and [Philosophie de l'odorat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/549148093) (2010). The latter book reproduces the false citation on page 104. Unfortunately, I could not get any hint from this book of where her confusion about this citation came from.

Answer (score 36):

### It was an urban legend years before the alleged 1981 origin

I was able to find some snippets and they mostly throw doubt on it being a real Napoleon quote, not least because it's been attributed to so many other people. (There's no evidence that any of them said it either!) Because they come from Google Books, I can't be certain that the years are accurate, though I tried to verify each one by searching for other years.

[L'Entente du couple](https://books.google.com/books?id=VGJcMaBH1tcC&q=%22J%27arrive,%20ne%20te%20lave%20pas.%22&dq=%22J%27arrive,%20ne%20te%20lave%20pas.%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSz_yFlPP8AhWkElkFHbh8B6AQ6AF6BAgEEAI), 1970:

> «J'arrive, ne te lave pas...» écrivait Napoléon à Joséphine. Je pense souvent à ce cri de sensualité lorsque je vois ces affiches publicitaires invitant à bannir toute odeur corporelle et à transformer tout corps en fraîche salade.

Translation via Google:

> "I'm coming, don't wash..." wrote Napoleon to Josephine. I often think of this cry of sensuality when I see these advertising posters inviting to banish all body odor and to transform any body into a fresh salad.

[Des Français: roman](https://books.google.com/books?id=p0knAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Ne%20te%20lave%20pas,%20j%27arrive%22&dq=%22Ne%20te%20lave%20pas,%20j%27arrive%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicx725lPP8AhVWD1kFHVLHCzkQ6AF6BAgFEAI), 1970:

> ...heureuse de briller par un détail qu'elle tenait de Francis, dit que cette négligence avait peut - être un fond aristocratique, puisque Henri IV écrivait à sa maîtresse: «Ne te lave pas, j'arrive.» Ce roi prétendait, du reste, qu'un bon gentilhomme doit avoir «les pieds fumants et l'aisselle suète».

Translation via Google:

> ...happy to shine by a detail she had learned from Francis, said that this negligence had perhaps an aristocratic background, since Henri IV wrote to his mistress: "Don't wash yourself, I'm coming." This king claimed, moreover, that a good gentleman should have "steaming feet and sweaty armpits."

[Skin Health and Beauty](https://books.google.com/books?id=tBENAQAAMAAJ&q=%22te%20lave%20pas%22%20j%27arrive&dq=%22te%20lave%20pas%22%20j%27arrive&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiepbDlj_P8AhWOFlkFHXAVCe4Q6AF6BAgIEAI), 1969:

> Baudelaire, who had been vacationing in the south of France, upon deciding to return to Paris telegraphed his mistress, “Ne te lave pas. J'arrive demain.” (Don't wash. I'm coming home tomorrow.)

[An American Romance: The Alan Poems, a Journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=gJc2AQAAIAAJ&q=%22Baudelaire%22%20%22Don%27t%20wash%22&dq=%22Baudelaire%22%20%22Don%27t%20wash%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTusXlkPP8AhVBFFkFHSmkDQoQ6AF6BAgJEAI), 1969:

> Was it Baudelaire, to his mistress, sent the wire 'Due back in Paris in three days; don't wash'?

### Before that, nothing

For something that was allegedly said by several famous people who died over a hundred years prior, there is no trail in Google Books dating back any further than that. It's not in [Les lettres ardentes de Napoléon à Joséphine](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6304095n.texteImage) or [Napoleon's Letters to Josephine](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/37499/37499-h/37499-h.htm). The latter, however, has some other quotes by Napoleon about baths:

> - Corvisart tells me that it is a good sign that the baths are having the desired effect, and that your health will soon be re-established.
> - You say nothing of your health nor of the effect of the baths
> - Advise me by the courier what you intend to do, and how soon you expect to end your baths.

With this explanatory text:

> The waters.—Mlle. d'Avrillon describes them and their effect—the sulphur baths giving erysipelas to people in poor health. Corvisart had accompanied the Empress, to superintend their effect, which was as usual nil.

Comment: Yeah sounds like the doing of a bored and possibly greedy historian, who wanted to get famous so faked up something. Without the actual letter, it's impossible to prove such ridiculous claims.

Comment: If she was taking sulfur baths, I can certainly understand why he'd ask her not to bathe! :)

Comment: thank you very much for the insightful answer! As it seems, @DavePhD may have found a slightly older claim from 1967. Maybe this could be incorporated into this answer? I'm still curious about whether the claim can actually be found in the 1981 book "Lettres d’amour à Joséphine", whose authors seem to be reputable historians. But this book is not available in my local libraries (no surprise).

Comment: Also a bit of a racist stereotype, given that all of the purported sources for the quote are French, no doubt actually made up by English or Americans who have long had this opinion of the French.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Well, a stereotype, but by the time these claims were made, Americans weren't generally treating various nationalities from Western Europe as separate *races*; they'd all become "white". But yes, national/cultural stereotypes are still a thing.

Comment: "... and how soon you expect to end your baths".  This sounds like something that a liberal *interpreter* could transcribe into 'don't bathe'.

Comment: @mcalex It doesn't fit. He's not asking her to stop bathing and while he is telling her where he'll be in the upcoming days, he's not going to see her.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The word "racism" and "race" may have connected roots, but saying that "racism" can't exist in a situation because of the use of the word "race" at the time is frankly ridiculous at best.  At worst, it is racism apology.

Comment: @Yakk I don't understand, you suggest that the French are a race? The American use of the word "racism" is extremely imprecise. The primary message of the comment (if I get it correctly) was that it is not a racist stereotype but a national one. It seems like a great over-exaggeration to say it is a "racism apology" because (if I understand it correctly), it is only focusing on the language side and does not claim anything about morality.

Comment: @skywalker Saying "the prejudiced against group in this specific case isn't against something I personally would label as a race, so using racism is wrong" is the opposite of helpful.  It neither clarifies meaning of what is being communicated nor produces an important difference in what is being corrected, and it places one specific definition of "racism" above others, so the correction isn't even correct!  "I prefer not to use the word racism for that form of prejudice" could be correct (and utterly uninteresting!), but "that isn't racism" is incorrect (and a useless contribution).

Comment: Looks like **"_You say nothing of your health nor of the effect of the baths. I see that you expect to be home in a week; that is good news for your lover, who is tired of being alone!_"** is a possible source.  It sounds like Napoleon was saying that he was happy that she was going to stop her bathing so that, in a few days, they could have sex.  Of course, the context would seem significant to understanding the quote.

Comment: Not immediately seeing information about the particular story behind Josephine's sulfur-baths, but it sounds like it was probably a spa-like sulfur-spring that she traveled to.  So guessing that she had to stop "_bathing_", i.e. being at the sulfur-springs, to return to Napoleon.  Though we might speculate that Napoleon would've hoped for Josephine to thoroughly bath in more conventional baths first.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I heard this anecdote, only about Henry IV, (a) 30+ years ago, long before seeing stereotypes everywhere came into vogue—to me, it sounded suspicious of a medieval stereotype, tho—but who in their sane mind would relate the medieval to modern French, and the more so as if the French were a race; and (b) in Europe, not from Americans or the Brits, so it's most likely salience bias: most of the information available on the Internet is in English, especially if you query is in English. I'm sure you'll find it in almost any language spoken in Europe; it _will_ be harder to find.

Answer (score 5):

The earliest example I see so far of this claim is from 1963:

See [Car and Driver](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sports_Cars_Illustrated/nVlWAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22fortnight,%20don%27t%20bathe%22&dq=%22fortnight,%20don%27t%20bathe%22&printsec=frontcover) volume 8, June 1963, page 75 (alternative [link](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000517644?type%5B%5D=all&lookfor%5B%5D=sports%20cars%20illustrated&ft=) to University of Michigan source):

> Your room , which will be spotless , will cost you about six or seven dollars a day including your petit déjeuner , rolls and coffee . If your wife complains about the bath being down the hall or perhaps not on the same floor , tell her what Napoleon wrote his empress , Josephine : " I'll be home in a fortnight ; don't bathe . "

Also, the July 1967 [L'Express](https://www.google.com/books/edition/L_Express/vePlAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (alternative [links](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000496118?type%5B%5D=publisher&lookfor%5B%5D=presse-union&ft=) to Indiana University and University of Michigan sources) says:

> MEDECINE

> Le vrai moteur de la sexualité

> Rentrant de campagne , Napoléon ne manquait jamais d'avertir Joséphine : « J'arrive , ne te lave pas . » Ce qui était la marque chez l'Empereur d'un sûr instinct biologique , affirment les spécialistes modernes des problèmes de l'odorat.

> Ils étaient réunis à Cannes , le mois dernier , pour le V Symposium européen de leur discipline, et ils étaient tous d'accord pour constater , peut - être avec une pointe de nostalgie : « Peu à peu , la civilisation a fait passer au premier plan certains types de sensations , la vue , le toucher , l'ouïe. Mais si l'on en croit l'exemple animal , le vrai moteur de la sexualité , c'est l'odorat . »

> Le fait est connu depuis longtemps chez les insectes  L'odeur des dames papillons fait accourir les mâles, de plusieurs kilomètres à la ronde . En reconstituant cette En reconstituant cette odeur de façon synthé- [end of column]

> L'EXPRESS  10-16 juil . 1967

(issue 838, the week of 10-16 July 1967, page 29, right most column)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google Books doesn't always give accurate dates of publication! My best guess for the year of publication is 1992. See for example the results for [1990](https://books.google.com/books?id=vePlAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gb_mobile_entity&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&hl=en&gl=US&focus=searchwithinvolume#1990) which are more visible.

Comment: @Laurel if you search "Juillet 1967" and similar within the book you get lots of hits, google will show partial images.  I added one to the answer.  Google is wrong about years, but here google is specifying the month and the inside search matches the month.

Comment: @Laurel the one mention of 1990 is in a sentence about further plans, versus 69 results for "1967".

Comment: @Laurel also, Hathi Trust gives links to the 1967 issues separately from U. Indiana and U. Michigan and they both confirm it is from 1967.  https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000496118?type%5B%5D=publisher&lookfor%5B%5D=presse-union&ft=

Comment: There is no "University of Indiana" your citations are to sources from *Indiana University*.

Comment: Fun fact: there are natural sulfur water springs in southern Indiana, and there was once a booming sulfur-water bottling and distribution business business there, as well as luxury resorts featuring sulfur water baths.  This may have something to do with why Indiana University sources had such an interest.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , ok, sorry, I fixed in the answer

Comment: I believe this would be better with an English translation.